# PL/SQL - Triggers Count

Tags: plsql, triggers

i have the following tables:

```
Piers(PierID, Name, NumOfShips)
Ships(ShipID, Name)
Docking(PierID, ShipID)
```

I need to implement a trigger which will count how many ships each pier contains and insert the results into `NumOfShips`.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER change_on_Ships
AFTER UPDATE ON Ships
BEGIN
   UPDATE Piers 
      SET NumOfShips = (
          SELECT count(1) FROM Docking d
           WHERE d.PierID = ( 
              SELECT PierID FROM Docking where ShipId = :NEW.ShipID 
           )
      )
    WHERE PierID = (select PierID from Docking where ShipID = :NEW.ShipID );
END;
```

hope it helps